# XPath query is not working in IXMLDOMDocument2, but passes online XPath tester

Tags: c++, xml, winapi, xpath

In the below XML, I'm trying to use an XPath query to select the first `<Event>` node that has `RenderingInfo/Task = StartRemoteSessionRdpClientBegin`.

```xml
<Events>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Guid="{9e814aad-3204-11d2-9a82-006008a86939}" />
        <EventID>0</EventID>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="EventVersion">0</Data>
        <Data Name="Reserved">0</Data>
        <Data Name="PartitionType">       0</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
        <Opcode>PartitionInfoExtensionV2</Opcode>
        <Provider>MSNT_SystemTrace</Provider>
        <EventName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">EventTrace</EventName>
    </RenderingInfo>
    <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
        <EventGuid>{68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}</EventGuid>
    </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft.Windows.HVSI.Manager" Guid="{5e3f60ef-a60f-45a9-84ae-e224f761baa3}" />
        <EventID>0</EventID>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="ContainerName">2fb583e6-3769-4465-9de0-ce56a1aa84c4</Data>
        <Data Name="RDPSessionID">{24259afa-2028-4206-9856-257ea519bfdd}</Data>
        <Data Name="PartA_PrivTags">16777216</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
        <Task>StartRemoteSessionRdpClientBegin</Task>
    </RenderingInfo>
</Event>
</Events>
```

From W3School examples I've looked at, I'd think this should be possible with an XPath query like: `/Events/Event[RenderingInfo/Task="StartRemoteSessionRdpClientBegin"]`.

I've tried this with my XML at https://www.uccollabing.com/free-online-xpath-tester-evaluator-tool/ and it seemed to work there, which makes me suspect an issue with my code. Simple queries work e.g. `/Events` or `/Events/*`.

Should my above query work?

```cpp
HRESULT SearchTraceFile(std::wstring fileName)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    _bstr_t xPath = L"/Events/Event[RenderingInfo/Task=\"StartRemoteSessionRdpClientBegin\"]";
    wprintf(L"Query path: %s\n", static_cast<wchar_t*>(xPath));

    RETURN_IF_FAILED(CoInitialize(NULL));

    wrl::ComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> xmlDoc;
    RETURN_IF_FAILED(CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_DOMDocument60,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IXMLDOMDocument2, (void**)&xmlDoc));

    _variant_t localFileName(fileName.c_str());
    VARIANT_BOOL successful = VARIANT_FALSE;
    RETURN_IF_FAILED(xmlDoc->load(localFileName, &successful));
    RETURN_HR_IF(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INVALID_DATA), (successful != VARIANT_TRUE));

    _variant_t varXPath(L"XPath");
    xmlDoc->setProperty(L"SelectionLanguage", varXPath);
    xmlDoc->setProperty(L"MaxElementDepth", CComVariant(10));

    wrl::ComPtr<IXMLDOMNodeList> events;
    wrl::ComPtr<IXMLDOMNode> spTaskNode;

    hr = xmlDoc->selectSingleNode(xPath, &spTaskNode);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    if (S_FALSE == hr)
    {
        wprintf(L"Not found\n");
        return S_OK;
    }

    BSTR value = NULL;
    hr = spTaskNode->get_text(&value);
    if (FAILED(hr)) wprintf(L"get_text failed 0x%08x\n", hr);
    else wprintf(L"get_text succedded\n");

    wprintf(L"value:\n%s\n", value);
    ::SysFreeString(value);

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `xmlDoc->selectSingleNode()` when you try?

Comment: It's returning S_FALSE which is documented as not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML involves namespaces, so you have to take that into account in your XPath query. This is documented on MSDN:

[Specify Namespace when you query the DOM with XPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/msxml/specify-namespace-querying-dom-xpath)

For example:

```cpp
HRESULT SearchTraceFile(std::wstring fileName)
{
    _bstr_t xPath = L"/Events/e:Event[e:RenderingInfo/e:Task=\"StartRemoteSessionRdpClientBegin\"]"; // <-- NOTE THE 'e:' PREFIXES!
    wprintf(L"Query path: %s\n", static_cast<wchar_t*>(xPath));

    RETURN_IF_FAILED(CoInitialize(NULL));

    wrl::ComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> xmlDoc;
    RETURN_IF_FAILED(CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_DOMDocument60,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IXMLDOMDocument2, (void**)&xmlDoc));

    _variant_t localFileName(fileName.c_str());
    VARIANT_BOOL successful = VARIANT_FALSE;
    RETURN_IF_FAILED(xmlDoc->load(localFileName, &successful));
    RETURN_HR_IF(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INVALID_DATA), (successful != VARIANT_TRUE));

    xmlDoc->setProperty(L"SelectionLanguage", _variant_t(L"XPath"));
    xmlDoc->setProperty(L"SelectionNamespaces", _variant_t(L"xmlns:e='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'")); // <-- ADD THIS!
    xmlDoc->setProperty(L"MaxElementDepth", _variant_t(10));

    wrl::ComPtr<IXMLDOMNodeList> events;
    wrl::ComPtr<IXMLDOMNode> spTaskNode;

    HRESULT hr = xmlDoc->selectSingleNode(xPath, &spTaskNode);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        wprintf(L"selectSingleNode failed 0x%08x\n", hr);
        return hr;
    }

    if (S_FALSE == hr)
    {
        wprintf(L"Not found\n");
        return S_OK;
    }

    _bstr_t value;
    hr = spTaskNode->get_text(value.GetAddress());
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        wprintf(L"get_text failed 0x%08x\n", hr);
        return hr;
    }

    wprintf(L"get_text succeeded\nvalue:\n%s\n", static_cast<wchar_t*>(value));

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I made the two changes suggested and still get the same S_FALSE. Did I miss something?

Comment: Try ```"/Events/e:Event[e:RenderingInfo/e:Task=\"...\"]"```